# Flask: Dumping "request.data" in middleware?

Tags: flask

I know that at the middleware level the concept of "request" doesn't exist yet because the request object hasn't been initialized.

However, I find it very helpful if I can dump `request.data` in the middleware layer so I don't have to liter `pprint(request.data)` all over my application file.

Can someone tell me a way to do this at the middle layer level?

Comment: Take into account that the wsgi.input reference is a *file object*, you may want to seek back to 0 before passing on the WSGI environment to the next layer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried `environ['wsgi.input'].seek(0)` I am getting a `IOError: [Errno 29] Illegal seek`

Comment: It depend on the WSGI server wether that is available. I guess you could replace that object with a `io.BytesIO` object with the full contents from a read from the old object. Only do that when the seek fails.